# How to ungroup compilations on iPhone Music?

Tags: iphone, itunes, music

I have several "compilation" albums, or albums with more than one artist, in my music library.

On the iTunes app in my computer, I can set "Group Compilations" option off to ungroup the compilations in my library; in other words, it makes those songs show up under the specific artist instead of under "Various Artists."

However, this isn't the case on my iPhone. In my Music app, those compilation songs don't show up under their respective artists; they show up under the "Compilations" tab instead.

Is there a way to turn a "Group Compilations" setting off on the iPhone, like you can do in iTunes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fingaz's answer is not quite correct—they are talking about when you uncheck the "compilation" box in the Get Info window in iTunes, not turning off "Group Compilations".

The short answer is no, at least not at this time. If you want them to not be grouped as a separate "artist", you would need to alter the metadata in iTunes such that they aren't compilations any more. If this is a feature you would like to see in the Music app, you can tell Apple yourself on [this page](http://www.apple.com/feedback/apple-music.html).

Answer (score 0):

The music is synced from the computer and the iPhone is just mimicking the computers library. Once these changes have been made on the computer you will need to sync the iPhone with the computer again.

The reason why there is not a solution on the phone is from the user interface not including an editing option for metadata, which is what is being changed on the computer. I personally feel this would convolute the interface, especially with Apple Music now available.